# looping foreach return duplicate data

Tags: php, arrays

I have 3 data array like this

```
$array_a = [
    ['id' => 1,'name' => 'name1'],
    ['id' => 2,'name' => 'name2'],
    ['id' => 3,'name' => 'name3'],
];

$array_b = [
    ['id' => 1,'tax' => 'tax1'],
    ['id' => 2,'tax' => 'tax2'],
    ['id' => 3,'tax' => 'tax3'],
];

$data = [
    ['id' => 1, 'id_ar_a' => 1,'id_ar_b' => 1, 'total' => 1111],
    ['id' => 2, 'id_ar_a' => 2,'id_ar_b' => 1, 'total' => 2222],
    ['id' => 3, 'id_ar_a' => 3,'id_ar_b' => 1, 'total' => 3333],
    ['id' => 4, 'id_ar_a' => 1,'id_ar_b' => 2, 'total' => 4444],
    ['id' => 5, 'id_ar_a' => 2,'id_ar_b' => 2, 'total' => 5555],
    ['id' => 6, 'id_ar_a' => 3,'id_ar_b' => 2, 'total' => 6666],
];
```

and my code like this

```
foreach ($data as $v => $dt) {
    foreach ($array_a as $i => $ara) {
        foreach ($array_b as $j => $arb) {
            if (($dt['id_ar_a'] == $ara['id']) && ($arb['id'] == $dt['id_ar_b'])) {
                echo "<input value='".$dt['total']."'><br>";
                unset($data[$v]);    
            } else {
                echo "<input value='0'><br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the result from my code

[image]

I want to get result like this

[image]

as you can see `count($array_a) = 3` and `count($array_b) = 3`
and total of my `$data` is 6 rows

I need to **get 9 rows** based on `$array_a` X `$array_b` with `default value = 0;`
i'm already trying to use `unset()` but still not working.
so how to unset or remove duplicate data from multiples looping?

Comment: Unsetting during the loop won't have any effect. It's looping over a copy of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the 0 input for every non-matching element in the two arrays. You need to wait until the end of the loops over `$array_a` and `$array_b`, and create the `0` input if you didn't find a match.

It's simpler if you put the `$data` loop as the innermost loop.

```
foreach ($array_a as $i => $ara) {
    foreach ($array_b as $j => $arb) {
        $found = false;
        foreach ($data as $v => $dt) {
            if (($dt['id_ar_a'] == $ara['id']) && ($arb['id'] == $dt['id_ar_b'])) {
                echo "<input value='".$dt['total']."'><br>";
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!$found) {
            echo "<input value='0'><br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Barmar's answer, if you want the output with exact order in your answer try this:

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($array_a as $i => $ara) {
    foreach ($array_b as $j => $arb) {
        $found = false;
        foreach ($data as $v => $dt) {
            if (($dt['id_ar_a'] == $ara['id']) && ($arb['id'] == $dt['id_ar_b'])) {
                echo "<input value='" . $dt['total'] . "'><br>";
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!$found) $count++;
    }
}

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo "<input value='0'><br>";
}
```